# How to load sframe format file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sframe

Is there any way to directly open `.sframe` extension file in pandas.
Like an easy way

```
df = pd.read_csv('people.sframe')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't import `sframe` files directly with Pandas. Rather you can use a free python library named `sframe`:

```
import sframe
import pandas as pd

sf = sframe.SFrame('people.sframe')
```

Then you can convert it to a pandas DataFrame using:

```
df = sf.to_dataframe()
```

Comment: oh, sadly, Thanks anyway, I didnt wanted to install sframe because of proprietery, but anyway, this method is great thank you :)